# How to make buttons in a SwiftUI Grid expand to fill minimum column width?

Tags: swiftui

I have a SwiftUI Grid with buttons in each cell of a column. Some buttons have labels wider than others. At the moment, the buttons are all at the minimum width that will accommodated their own titles.

I would like all the buttons to have the width of the widest of those buttons (presumably the same width as the column itself).

Here's an illustrative example:

```
struct GridTest: View {
    var body: some View {
        Grid {
            GridRow {
                Text("First Row")
                Button {
                } label: {
                    Text("Button")
//                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                }
                .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
            }
            GridRow {
                Text("Second Row")
                Button {
                } label: {
                    Text("Button with Longer Title")
//                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                }
                .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Here's what the result looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXNdj.png)

The solution that is suggested in some contexts is to set the max-width for the buttons to .infinity. Uncommenting the two lines in the example code above expands the buttons beyond the intended width.

[Here's what that looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Z0xY.png)

In case it's not clear, [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSHF5.png) is what I would hope for, as a result.

Does anyone know how to solve this layout problem?

Answer (score 0):

### Matching the known widest button

[image: Demo running in simulator]

If you know which button in your grid column is the widest, you can make the other buttons in the column match its width by adding `.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)` and [`.gridCellUnsizedAxes(.horizontal)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/gaugestyleconfiguration/maximumvaluelabel-swift.struct/gridcellunsizedaxes(_:)?changes=latest_beta) to the shorter buttons.  For example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Grid {
            GridRow {
                Text("First Row")
                Button {
                } label: {
                    Text("Button")
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)

                }
                .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
                .gridCellUnsizedAxes(.horizontal)
            }

            GridRow {
                Text("Second Row")
                Button {
                } label: {
                    Text("Medium Button")
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)

                }
                .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
                .gridCellUnsizedAxes(.horizontal)
            }

            GridRow {
                Text("Third Row")
                Button {
                } label: {
                    Text("Button with Longer Title")
                }
                .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

### Alternate Solution: Brainstorming - Using `ZStack` and `.opacity`

This is (admittedly) a dirty hack, but perhaps it will give you inspiration.  Put the Text Views for every button in your grid that are in the same column in a `ZStack` and mark the unused ones with `.opacity(0)`.  This will cause all of the buttons to be the same width:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Grid {
            GridRow {
                Text("First Row")
                Button {
                } label: {
                    ZStack {
                        Text("Button with Longer Title").opacity(0)
                        Text("Button")
                    }
                }
                .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
            }
            GridRow {
                Text("Second Row")
                Button {
                } label: {
                    ZStack {
                        Text("Button with Longer Title")
                        Text("Button").opacity(0)
                    }
                }
                .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

### Making it more usable

Create a view called `GridButtonText` which takes a list of titles and the index to present, and have it create the `ZStack`:

```
struct GridButtonText: View {
    let show: Int
    let titles: [String]

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ForEach(0..<titles.count, id: \.self) { index in
                Text(titles[index]).opacity(index == show ? 1 : 0)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let buttonTitles = ["Button", "Button with Longer Title"]
    var body: some View {
        Grid {
            GridRow {
                Text("First Row")
                Button {
                } label: {
                    GridButtonText(show: 0, titles: buttonTitles)
                }
                .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
            }
            GridRow {
                Text("Second Row")
                Button {
                } label: {
                    GridButtonText(show: 1, titles: buttonTitles)
                }
                .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
            }
        }
    }
}
```